# Is SQL Azure Data Sync Production Ready?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I want to start using SQL Azure and SQL Azure Data Sync (for both on-premises SQL 2008 and Azure).

The Azure Portal still labels data sync 'Preview' - so is it even production ready?

If not when will it be?

Answer (score 1):

Anything labeled as "In-Preview" is considered not supported for production use, though you may opt to do so; just realize that it is currently not recommended.  As for timing, I suggest keeping tabs on the SQL team's blog: http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/