# SQL Data Sync still on preview

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We have the need to sync an Azure SQL Database (PaaS) with a SQL Server on-premises instance (on customer’s DataCenter), as both are being fed with data from different systems. Both databases share the same schema, and we need the sync process to be bidirectional, where every 5 minutes the data from the Azure SQL Database goes down and every hour the data from the SQL Server (Standard) instance goes up.

We thought of using SQL Data Sync (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync), as its the most straightforward solution to achieve what we want, were almost no configuration or custom code is needed. The main problem is that it’s still on Preview, and it has been like that for some years. So, my questions are:

1) Why is it still on preview?

2) What other alternatives would you consider for this requirement, without losing transparency and performance?

PS: There's a similar question form almost 3 years ago ([Is SQL Azure Data Sync Production Ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994419/is-sql-azure-data-sync-production-ready))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be GA this month.

SSIS could be another solution but it requires certain domain knowledge and effort to create an maintain the solution.

Comment: Any evidence on that? Because I read a blog post that said that it was going to be on GA in 2017

Comment: Probably best not to talk about unannounced things here on a public forum.

Comment: @GabrielPiffaretti He is a Program Manager on Azure SQL Database team. When I have questions about Azure SQL Data Sync I email him and his team. You have received a first hand information.

Comment: @GabrielPiffaretti, Unfortunately, you need to wait for another few days for the evidence. But you can start to use the service today. If you can send me the link of the old blog post, I can update or delete it. :)

Comment: Here's the post. It's on a forum though, my bad. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/71456278-3aae-4215-a33b-9a3210b4e281/azure-sql-data-sync-in-production?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: Thank you all, I'll be waiting for the official confirmation!